# Chrome extension inline installation

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, opentok

I'm installing a Chrome extension "inline" (without the user leaving the page).

```
chrome.webstore.install("https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/<id>")
```

This is the OpenTok function that checks for screen sharing capability.

```
OT.checkScreenSharingCapability(function(response){
    console.log("CHECKED", response)
    console.log("extensionRegistered", response.extensionRegistered)
    console.log("extensionInstalled", response.extensionInstalled)
});
```

When I run this `checkScreenSharingCapability` function before the inline installation, I get `extensionRegistered: true` and `extensionInstalled: false`.

Then, the inline installation happens. I can now see the extension installed in chrome://extensions/, but when I run the `checkScreenSharingCapability` function again, I get the same results: `extensionRegistered: true` and `extensionInstalled: false`

---

When I refresh the page, now the `checkScreenSharingCapability` function responds with the expected result: `extensionRegistered: true` and `extensionInstalled: true`. But I want to get this inline extension installation to work without refreshing the page (isn't that the whole point of the inline installer??)

Comment: I think you have to refresh the page for the extension to work from manifest.json, but you can inject a JavaScript script to the page after you install the extension, without refreshing the page.

Comment: What is the nature of your extension?  conent-script and/or event-page?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Let me know if you found a sloution to it. :(